# Stop parallax from resizing my window

Tags: html, css, frontend, parallax

I'm new to front end and i'm trying to make a page that is cant be scrolled. I want it to be the size of my background. When I position my the hand image at the bottom of the page it resizes the window. The window scroll bar even slides on its own when the hand moves. How do I make sure to keep the size fixed?

html -

```
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul id="scene">
                <li class="layer" id="bluelayer" data-depth="0.0"><img src="{%  static 'images/aboutus/BlueLayer.png' %}"></li>
                <li class="layer" id="booklayer" data-depth="0.0"><img src="{%  static 'images/aboutus/Book.png' %}"></li>
                <li class="layer" id="coffeelayer" data-depth="0.0"><img src="{%  static 'images/aboutus/Coffee.png' %}"></li>
                <li class="layer" id="handslayer" data-depth="0.6"><img src="{%  static 'images/aboutus/Hands.png' %}"></li>
                <li class="layer" id="keyboardlayer" data-depth="0.0"><img src="{%  static 'images/aboutus/Keyboard.png' %}"></li>
                <li class="layer" id="pencilonelayer" data-depth="0.0"><img src="{%  static 'images/aboutus/Pencil1.png' %}"></li>
                <li class="layer" id="penciltwolayer" data-depth="0.0"><img src="{%  static 'images/aboutus/Pencil2.png' %}"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css -

```
body {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background: none;
}

.full {
    background: url(../images/aboutus/Desk.jpg) no-repeat center center 
fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

}


#bluelayer {
    margin-left: -9.5em;
    margin-top: -50px;
    width: auto;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
}

#booklayer {
    margin-left: -5em;
    margin-top: 350px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#coffeelayer {
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: 80em;
    z-index: 1;
}

#handslayer {
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: 25em;
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
}

#keyboardlayer {
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: 25em;
    z-index: 1;
}

#pencilonelayer {
    margin-top: 550px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#penciltwolayer {
    margin-top: 450px;
    margin-left: 70em;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Set up a quick jsfiddle up for us, please.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try `overflow: hidden;` on the container to start. I'm not 100% clear on what you're working with here